# Web Developer advice required

Tags: job-search, new-job, software-development, software-engineering

I have 5 years of vanilla PHP web development experience using Bootstrap, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. In Hertfordshire, I earn £30,000, but I need £40,000 for a mortgage. I’ve been applying for jobs, reaching the last stage, but they all require knowledge of PHP frameworks. I’m unsure how to proceed and feel demoralised after losing opportunities to juniors due to lack of framework and testing knowledge. Any advice on the best path forward?

Comment: Not a Workplace answer, so just keeping it a comment.... if you need a 33% salary increase for a long-term loan like a mortgage, you may need to re-evaluate your financial situation. It feels like you risk bankrupting yourself chasing big loans.

Comment: Ah, you are aware that - cough - prices are falling and people are GETTING LET GO everywhere now?

Answer (score 3):

I would say self-study and persistence.

Invest some time in learning the required skills for your desired position, create some project you can demonstrate.

And apply to positions, matching your criteria.
Sooner or later you will get the offer you need

Comment: A lot of PHP frameworks are completely free. Just grab them, go through tutorials, and convert an existing project to use the framework.

Comment: Not gonna help - the west (and he is in the UK) is falling into a deep recession. heck, buying anything NOW is likely a bad, really bad move, especially in the UK. One of the most ridiculous surreal governments in the planet hell bent on ruining the country.